# how to send notification to user on data change in realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]
the problem is if there is any change in notification/154578/0 or in notification/154580/0 (and more child with different id) I need a firebase cloud function (index.js) that will be triggered on data change and fetch the id from notification ether data changed in 154578 id or in 154580, get that particular id and move to eg: fcm-token/154578/value : sldal9854dfas (<- it also in realtime database shibling of notification)  get this value and send notification to this token.
Actually I'm a beginner I don't know how to do this if anyone can help me, it would be great help for me
thank you.

Comment: You need to use Firebase cloud function. You can learn more about it over [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.